# Fastest way to compare ordered lists and count common elements *including* duplicates

Tags: python

I need to compare two lists of numbers and count how many elements of first list are there in second list. For example,

```
a =  [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
b1 = [0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

here I should get result of 4: I should count '2' 1 time (as it happens only once in first list), '3' - 2 times, '4' - 1 time (as it happens only once in second list). I was using the following code:

```
def scoreIn(list1, list2):
   score=0
   list2c=list(list2)
   for i in list1:
      if i in list2c:
         score+=1
         list2c.remove(i)
   return score
```

it works correctly, but too slow for my case (I call it 15000 times). I read a hint about 'walking' through sorted lists which was supposed to be faster, so I tried to do like that:

```
def scoreWalk(list1, list2):
   score=0
   i=0
   j=0
   len1=len(list1) # we assume that list2 is never shorter than list1
   while i<len1:
      if list1[i]==list2[j]:
         score+=1
         i+=1
         j+=1
      elif list1[i]>list2[j]:
         j+=1
      else:
         i+=1
   return score
```

Unfortunately this code is even slower. Is there any way to make it more efficient? In my case, both lists are sorted, contains only integers, and list1 is never longer than list2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the intersection feature of `collections.Counter` to solve the problem in an easy and readable way:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> intersection = Counter( [2,3,3,4,4,5] ) & Counter( [0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 8] )
>>> intersection
Counter({3: 2, 2: 1, 4: 1})
```

As @Bakuriu says in the comments, to obtain the *number* of elements in the intersection (including duplicates), like your `scoreIn` function, you can then use `sum( intersection.values() )`.

However, doing it this way you're not actually taking advantage of the fact that your data is pre-sorted, nor of the fact (mentioned in the comments) that you're doing this over and over again with the same list.

Here is a more elaborate solution more specifically tailored for your problem. It uses a `Counter` for the static list and directly uses the sorted dynamic list. On my machine it runs in 43% of the run-time of the naïve `Counter` approach on randomly generated test data.

```
def common_elements( static_counter, dynamic_sorted_list ):
    last = None # previous element in the dynamic list
    count = 0 # count seen so far for this element in the dynamic list

    total_count = 0 # total common elements seen, eventually the return value

    for x in dynamic_sorted_list:
        # since the list is sorted, if there's more than one element they
        # will be consecutive.
        if x == last:
            # one more of the same as the previous  element

            # all we need to do is increase the count
            count += 1
        else:
            # this is a new element that we haven't seen before.

            # first "flush out" the current count we've been keeping.
            #   - count is the number of times it occurred in the dynamic list
            #   - static_counter[ last ] is the number of times it occurred in
            #       the static list (the Counter class counted this for us)
            # thus the number of occurrences the two have in common is the
            # smaller of these numbers. (Note that unlike a normal dictionary,
            # which would raise KeyError, a Counter will return zero if we try
            # to look up a key that isn't there at all.)
            total_count += min( static_counter[ last ], count )

            # now set count and last to the new element, starting a new run
            count = 1
            last = x

    if count > 0:
        # since we only "flushed" above once we'd iterated _past_ an element,
        # the last unique value hasn't been counted. count it now.
        total_count += min( static_counter[ last ], count )

    return total_count
```

The idea of this is that you do some of the work up front when you create the `Counter` object. Once you've done that work, you can use the `Counter` object to quickly look up counts, just like you look up values in a dictionary: `static_counter[ x ]` returns the number of times `x` occurred in the static list.

Since the static list is the same every time, you can do this once and use the resulting quick-lookup structure 15 000 times.

On the other hand, setting up a `Counter` object for the dynamic list may not pay off performance-wise. There is a little bit of overhead involved in creating a `Counter` object, and we'd only use each dynamic list `Counter` one time. If we can avoid constructing the object at all, it makes sense to do so. And as we saw above, you can in fact implement what you need by just iterating through the dynamic list and looking up counts in the other counter.

The `scoreWalk` function in your post does not handle the case where the biggest item is only in the static list, e.g. `scoreWalk( [1,1,3], [1,1,2] )`. Correcting that, however, it actually performs *better* than any of the `Counter` approaches for me, contrary to the results you report. There may be a significant difference in the distribution of your data to my uniformly-distributed test data, but double-check your benchmarking of `scoreWalk` just to be sure.

Lastly, consider that you may be using the wrong tool for the job. You're not after short, elegant and readable -- you're trying to squeeze every last bit of performance out of a rather simple task. CPython allows you to [write modules in C](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html). One of the primary use cases for this is to implement highly optimized code. It may be a good fit for your task.

Comment: Add a `sum( expr.values())` to obtain the final count of common elements. (where `expr` is the `&` expression in the answer).

Comment: thanks, I did not know about this function! But unfortunately it does not give any gain in speed: according to profiler, it takes almost exactly the same time as my first algorithm.

Comment: @VasilyA Can you describe your input data in more detail? You need to do this 15,000 times on unrelated pairs of lists? Are the lists as short as the ones in your example, or much longer? The `collections.Counter` method isn't taking advantage of the fact that your data is already sorted.

Comment: Well, basically, I have one given 'spectrum' (which is the list of few hundreds integer numbers), and many thousands objects ('peptides') each having its own 'spectrum' (similar list of numbers), and the goal is to assign a score to each peptide - i.e. how close is each spectrum to the given one. I am of course ready to explain in more details but it can be a bit long to describe if you're not a bioinformatician (it is a task from basic bioinformatics course).

Comment: @VasilyA Have you tried generating the `Counter` objects for each spectrum first, and then performing only the intersection per pair? I would imagine that would give a major speedup compared to generating new `Counter` objects for every comparison.

Comment: for the objects I can't do exactly like that because they are generated dynamically: I need to do scoring for some portion, then generate another portion based on this scoring, etc. But with calculating and keeping Counter for the second list (that is always the same), I had indeed some gain: about 25% faster

Comment: @VasilyA Updated the answer. I'm puzzled by the results you're getting for `scoreWalk`. That is a perfectly sensible approach, and for me it's quite fast.

Comment: @svk, you are totally right that my code can't handle appropriately situation where the biggest item of list1 is not in list2 (I did not noticed myself because this never occurs in my dataset). Thank you for your algorithm, it seems to be faster indeed!

Comment: @svk, sorry for bothering - could you add just few words about the idea of your algorithm? I am trying to grasp it but my programming skills are too poor for that :/ For example, what is the meaning of `static_counter[ last ]`?

Comment: Now it's all clear, thank you so much! I really appreciate the time you spent for explaining this, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `dict` comprehension:

```
>>> a =  [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> b1 = [0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 8]
>>> {k: min(b1.count(k), a.count(k)) for k in set(a)}
{2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 0}
```

This is much faster if `set(a)` is small.  If `set(a)` is more than 40 items, the `Counter` based solution is faster.

Comment: well... for the moment it's not obvious for me how to get required answer with this approach, as it does not count duplicates in `a`.

Comment: it's still not really what I needed: in case of '2', it counts both occurrences in `b1` while I need to count only 1 (because it occurs only once in `a`)

Comment: I had forgotten to update the output, it counts only 1 for case '2'.  Try it out and see.